# NSDate() not returning UTC +000 after TestFlight installation

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, testflight, tvos

I'm a developer for streaming TV applications for Apple TV.
When I install a version of my app through test flight the date/time is not what I expected. I use NSDate() to retrieve it. As I expect this should return UTC +000, but it does not. To rule out mistakes in this assumption I also tried NSDateFormatter and use the locale of my Apple TV. My Apple TV's time/zone is set to Amsterdam. I display the outcome of NSDate() and the outcome after formatting. The result I see is: NSDate() is not UTC +000 and after formatting it, the result is not Amsterdam time/date.
This only happens after installing through test flight.
When I close my app, change the language of the Apple TV to another language and change it back to what it was, and reopen my app the results from NSDate() and the result from formatting is correct! Like the Apple TV made some refresh (note: I change the language not the time/zone).
Can someone tell me what happens here and what I am missing in my code?

```
    private func stringFromDateFormat() -> String {
    let dateFormatForFormatter:String = "dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm"
    let todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
    let locale:NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: locale.localeIdentifier)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormatForFormatter
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
    }
```

When I use the above function it does not return the Amsterdam time/date but on my Apple device this timezone is set. Again: it only happens when installing from test flight. And the strange language switch on my device I described above causes it to be right. Sometimes displaying NSDate() is several days of, the worse I experienced was 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code or app. Other apps I tried have the same issue also. It has to do with the Apple TV being unable to reach NTP. It seems that when starting the Apple TV it retrieves the current time/date I pick up with NSDate() from a stored value and the device is for some reason not able to refresh. When I change the language the Apple TV restarts/refreshes and afterwards is able to reach NTP.